# Oracle Union with order by clause issue

Tags: sql, oracle

Actual query looks something like this:

```
select to_char(first_name||'('||substr(last_name,0,1)||')') 
from employees 
order by first_name
union
select to_char('There are total '
||count(job_id)||' '||lower(job_id)||'s') 
from employees
group by job_id 
order by count(job_id),job_id;
```

individually both queries work but when I add Union to combine the result, I get following errorm in sql developer:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 2 Column: 1

I want to show all the records from the first query then all the records from the second query one after another, each set sorted in the order given above.

Comment: Can you provide data and the results you want?  That query may not be the best way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I just want to combine the records from first query and second query one after another

Comment: Add 1 to first select and 2 to second. Order by that column.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `to_char()` call does not make _any_ sense. `first_name` and `last_name` are already varchars so there is no need to convert them to a varchar using `to_char()`

Comment: Looks like your original error is that you have an order by in the first query still.  When using union/union all, there is only one order by at the end.  Read the answer below, it is pretty much spot on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying obstacle is that a SQL dataset is inherently UNordered.  As soon as you UNION two datasets you lose any guarantee of ordering previously present.

You can often get away with the following structure, but it is STILL not guaranteed...

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    (
        select to_char(first_name||'('||substr(last_name,0,1)||')') 
        from employees 
        order by first_name
    ) 
        Individuals

    UNION ALL

    (
        select to_char('There are total '||count(job_id)||' '||lower(job_id)||'s') 
        from employees
        group by job_id 
        order by count(job_id),job_id
    )
        Totals
)
    Combined
;
```

In practice you Often get what you want with this structure.

The brackets ensure the ordering is done before the UNION ALL and the database engine PROBABLY won't screw with the ordering.

But it MIGHT.  The only way to Guarantee the order of the results is to put an ORDER BY on the outer query.  Something like the following normally works fairly well...

```
SELECT
    rowdata
FROM
(
    (
        select 1 AS myset, rownum AS myrow, to_char(first_name||'('||substr(last_name,0,1)||')') AS rowdata
        from employees 
        order by first_name
    ) 
        Individuals

    UNION ALL

    (
        select 2 AS myset, rownum AS myrow, to_char('There are total '||count(job_id)||' '||lower(job_id)||'s') 
        from employees
        group by job_id 
        order by count(job_id),job_id
    )
        Totals
)
    Combined
ORDER BY
    myset, myrow
;
```

I'm on my phone, so there may be typos, but the sentiment is there...

Use ROWNUM or ROW_NUMBER() to generate an extra field in your data sets.  Then union them.  Then order by your new field(s).

Comment: These solutions do not work. The approach causes `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`. This is because ORDER BY is not allowed in the sub-queries of SET operations, which [is clearly documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries004.htm#SQLRF52341)..

Answer (score 2):

it should be work

```
    select to_char(first_name||'('||substr(last_name,0,1)||')') 
        from (select first_name, last_name from employees order by first_name)
    union
    select to_char('There are total '||cnt||' '||lower(job_id)||'s')
        from (select count(job_id) cnt, job_id from employees group by job_id 
order by count(job_id), job_id)
```

Comment: All answer kind of point me in the right direction and since I could only accept one answer as accepted answer. Have selected the one with most details. Thanks a lot of quick answers guys.

Comment: Vecchiasignora answer works.  The accepted answer does not work.  To order before the union, wrap it in another select statement.  Just used principle to order the rows and "fetch first 10 rows only" of one query.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do that is typically by supplying a column that identifies the "union group" in which a row should appear:

```
select name 
from (
  select first_name||'('||substr(last_name,0,1)||')' as name, 
         1 as sort_order, 
         0 as counter, 
         0 as job_id
  from employees 
  union all 
  select 'There are total '||count(job_id)||' '||lower(job_id)||'s', 
         2, 
         count(job_id), 
         job_id
  from employees
  group by job_id 
) t
order by sort_order, counter, job_id, name;
```

As you also want to sort the rows inside the second part by a different column, you need to create dummy columns for that, so that you can apply the correct `order by` on the overall result.

I also remove the useless `to_char()` calls from your query.

If `job_id` is in fact a `varchar` column (which the `lower(job_id)` seems to indicate), then you need to replace `0 as job_id` with some character constant. It doesn't really matter which value it is.

Online example: http://rextester.com/ZUPQ98121

Comment: @MatBailie: you are right, the `counter` needs to be the second sort column (which doesn't hurt for the first part as that value is the same for all rows there and thus they will be sorted by name)

Comment: @MatBailie: As I said, that doesn't matter because the job_id is 0 for all rows in the first set.